# Undefined index error from model class

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am getting this error sometimes when trying login. Intermittent.

```
[2015-05-31 03:41:48] local.ERROR: exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined index: interval' in /var/www/xxxx/app/Models/Person.php:44
```

**Model:**

```
class Person extends BaseModel
{
    protected $rules = array(
      'interval'  => 'required'
    );

    protected $appends = ['interval_formatted','buying_interval_formatted'];

    public function getIntervalFormattedAttribute()
    {
        return Self::formatIntervalFromSeconds($this->attributes['interval']);
    }

    public function getBuyingIntervalFormattedAttribute()
    {
        return Self::formatIntervalFromMinutes($this->attributes['buying_interval']);
    }
}
```

Help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Why are you using `$this->attributes['interval']`? You should use `$this->interval` and `$this->buying_interval` instead.